# Open a link at a specific time with C++

Tags: c++, url, time, hyperlink, console

So I am trying to write a C++ console program that opens a link with a web browser at a specific time. The clock updates fine and the shell line opens the link but I just can't get these two to work together. Here's my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
string url = "https://www.google.com";

while (true) {
    system("cls");
    time_t now = time(0);
    char* dt = ctime(&now);

    cout << dt;
    while (dt == "Mon May 18 09:48:00 2020") {
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", url.c_str(),
            NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least to me, your code seems a little confusing. It's not clear why we'd sleep for a second at a time until we reach the target. Worse, if one of the sleep calls happens to go a little too long, we could over-shoot the mark, and never carry out the desired action. And still worse, if we do reach the desired time, the inner loop looks like it's an infinite loop, since it continues to re-execute as long as the string has the desired time--but we're not updating the string to the current time in the loop, so if we do hit that time, the string will remain the same forever.

At least based on your description, we just want to pick a time, sleep until then, and then carry out the command. For that, it seems like code on this general order should suffice:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // For the moment, I'm just going to pick a time 10 seconds into the future:
    time_t now = time(nullptr);    
    now += 10;

    // compute that as a time_point, then sleep until then:
    auto then = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(now);
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(then);

    // and carry out the command:
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "https://www.google.com",
        NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

In your case, you apparently want to specify data and time. That's slightly more difficult to test, but fundamentally not a whole lot different. You can stuff the date/time you want into a `struct tm`, then use `mktime` to convert that to a `time_t`. Once you have a `time_t`, you use `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t`, as in the code above, and continue on from there. If you need to start from a string, you can use `std::get_time` to convert string data to a `struct tm`. So, for the date/time you've specified, we could do something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

auto convert(std::string const &s) {
    std::istringstream buffer(s);

    struct tm target_tm;
    buffer >> std::get_time(&target_tm, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
    time_t target = mktime(&target_tm);
    return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(target);
}

int main() {
    auto target = convert("Mon May 18 09:48:00 2020");

    std::this_thread::sleep_until(target);
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "https://www.google.com",
        NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Comment: Also: what if I want the program to continue after that and store a new time when it will open another link? Is that possible?

Comment: @VVahla: Sure. Once `ShellExecute` starts up the target program, you parent program just continues running normally, so you can do pretty much whatever you want.